# How do I do item configurations that are triggered by the user moving the image to a certain location on the canvas?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, configuration, hidden

In my program, there is an item that the user must 'obtain' by moving the level1_Player image over it. When the user does this, the item image and the star image behind it should now become HIDDEN and the level1_Player image should change to a different one of the player now holding the item. When I run my code, there is no error but nothing happens when the user moves the level1_Player image over the item image.

```
#function to check if the player has obtained the indicated object for level1
def level1_obtained():
    if level1_Player_x == 75 and level1_Player_y == 850:
        level1_canvas.itemconfig(level1_Jordans, state = HIDDEN)
        level1_canvas.itemconfig(level1_Star, state = HIDDEN)
        level1_canvas.itemconfig(level1_Player, image = playerWithJordans)

#functions to move the player image on the level 1 canvas
def left_level1(event):
    
    global level1_Player_x
    if level1_Player_x >= 75:
        level1_canvas.move(level1_Player, -10, 0)
        level1_Player_x = level1_Player_x -10
    level1_obtained()
    
def right_level1(event):
    
    global level1_Player_x
    if level1_Player_x <= 1925:
        level1_canvas.move(level1_Player, 10, 0)
        level1_Player_x = level1_Player_x +10
    level1_obtained()
    
def up_level1(event):
    
    global level1_Player_y
    if level1_Player_y >= 100:
        level1_canvas.move(level1_Player, 0, -10)
        level1_Player_y = level1_Player_y -10
    level1_obtained()

def down_level1(event):
    
    global level1_Player_y
    if level1_Player_y <= 1400:
        level1_canvas.move(level1_Player, 0, 10)
        level1_Player_y = level1_Player_y +10
    level1_obtained()

def level1():
    global level1_canvas, level1_Player, level1_Player_x, level1_Player_y, level1_Guard1, root4, level1_wall1, level1_wall2, level1_wall3, level1_wall4, level1_wall5, level1_wall6, level1_wall7

    
    #defining the x and y coordinates of the playerImage
    level1_Player_x = 1875
    level1_Player_y = 1375
    
    #close levelSelection page and open level1 page
    root3.destroy()
    root4 = Tk()
    
    #bring images into program to use
    player = PhotoImage(file = 'Player.png')
    exitSign = PhotoImage(file = 'exitSign.png')
    guard = PhotoImage(file = 'Guard.png')
    jordans = PhotoImage(file = 'Jordans.png')
    level1_star = PhotoImage(file = 'level1_star.png')
    playerWithJordans = PhotoImage(file = 'Player_Jordans.png')
    
    #binding KeyPress events to the pop up box
    root4.bind("<a>", left_level1)
    root4.bind("<d>", right_level1)
    root4.bind("<w>", up_level1)
    root4.bind("<s>", down_level1)
    root4.bind('<Left>', left_level1)
    root4.bind('<Right>', right_level1)
    root4.bind('<Up>', up_level1)
    root4.bind('<Down>', down_level1)
    
    #create a canvas for the level1 and put it into the root
    level1_canvas = Canvas(root4, height = 1500, width = 2000, bg = 'LightBlue3')
    level1_canvas.pack()
    
    #place images onto canvas
    level1_ExitSign = level1_canvas.create_image(1875, 100, image = exitSign)
    level1_Star = level1_canvas.create_image(75, 850, image = level1_star)
    level1_Jordans = level1_canvas.create_image(75, 850, image = jordans)
    level1_Player= level1_canvas.create_image(level1_Player_x, level1_Player_y, image = player)

mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the functions are being called? Have you examined variables to verify they are what you're assuming they are?

Comment: Yes, I have just finished re-checking everything and nothing seems to be out of place.

Comment: You never call `level1()` in you example code.  Also `level1_Jordans`, `level1_Star` and `playerWithJordans` are not declared global variables inside `level1()`, so they cannot be accessed inside `level1_obtained()`.